# Using purrr to extract values from nested dataframe based on condition

Tags: r, purrr

I'm working with a set of patient test results some of which are positive and negative. I'm reducing to individual patient level using `dplyr::nest()` and then extracting values for the first positive test only using `purrr::map()` and a function I've written. My dataset isn't huge - ~40k unique patients, ~110k test results - but I gave up running my script after 40 mins. I'm sure there's a better way of extracting these values but am struggling to work it out. The code chunk below illustrates the method I'm using (though obviously this runs in no time).

```
library(tidyverse)

example_data <- tribble(
  
  ~patient, ~is_first_positive, ~score_1, ~score_2,
  "A", F, 10, 45,
  "A", T, 16, 76,
  "A", F, 24, 86,
  "B", T, 17, 5,
  "B", F, 24, 22,
  "B", F, 55, 97,
  "C", F, 67, 48,
  "C", F, 23, 38,
  "C", F, 45, 16
  
)

example_data <- example_data %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  nest()

# function to extract values based on value of another column
get_field <- function(df, logical_field, rtn_field) {
  
  df <- df %>% filter_(logical_field)
  
  if(nrow(df)==0) {
    return(NA_integer_)
  } else {
    df %>% pull({{rtn_field}}) %>% as.integer() %>% return()
  }

}

# Use purrr to run function against each nested df
example_data <- example_data %>% 
  mutate(first_positive_score1 = map_int(data, ~get_field(., "is_first_positive", score_1)),
         first_positive_score2 = map_int(data, ~get_field(., "is_first_positive", score_2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can forgive the long lines, you can use `map()` in the following way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

example_data %>%
  mutate(score_1 = as.double(map(data, ~ deframe(.x[2])[which(deframe(.x[1]) == TRUE)])),
         score_2 = as.double(map(data, ~ deframe(.x[3])[which(deframe(.x[1]) == TRUE)]))) 

#   patient data             score_1 score_2
#   <chr>   <list>             <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A       <tibble [3 × 3]>      16      76
# 2 B       <tibble [3 × 3]>      17       5
# 3 C       <tibble [3 × 3]>      NA      NA
```

Comment: thank you - this did the trick. Processed the entire dataset with all of the columns in about 2 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that should be quite fast:

1. Filter to keep only first positive score
2. Merge back in the nested data if you need it

```r
library(tidyverse)

example_data <- tribble(
  ~patient, ~is_first_positive, ~score_1, ~score_2,
  "A", F, 10, 45,
  "A", T, 16, 76,
  "A", F, 24, 86,
  "B", T, 17, 5,
  "B", F, 24, 22,
  "B", F, 55, 97,
  "C", F, 67, 48,
  "C", F, 23, 38,
  "C", F, 45, 16
)

nested_data <- example_data %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  nest()

example_data %>% 
  filter(is_first_positive) %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  top_n(1) %>%
  full_join(nested_data)

#> Selecting by score_2
#> Joining, by = "patient"
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   patient [3]
#>   patient is_first_positive score_1 score_2 data            
#>   <chr>   <lgl>               <dbl>   <dbl> <list>          
#> 1 A       TRUE                   16      76 <tibble [3 × 3]>
#> 2 B       TRUE                   17       5 <tibble [3 × 3]>
#> 3 C       NA                     NA      NA <tibble [3 × 3]>
```

Considering your comment, I re-wrote your `get_field` function using Base R functions and was able to get a 10x speed improvement:

```r
get_field <- function(df, logical_field, rtn_field) {
  df <- df %>% filter_(logical_field)
  if(nrow(df)==0) {
    return(NA_integer_)
  } else {
    df %>% pull({{rtn_field}}) %>% as.integer() %>% return()
  }
}

get_field2 <- function(x, logical_field, rtn_field) {
  x <- x[x[[logical_field]], ]
  ifelse(nrow(x)==0, NA_integer_, x[[rtn_field]])
}

approach1 <- function() {
  example_data %>% 
  mutate(first_positive_score1 = map_int(data, ~get_field(., "is_first_positive", score_1)),
         first_positive_score2 = map_int(data, ~get_field(., "is_first_positive", score_2)))
}

approach2 <- function() {
  example_data %>% 
    mutate(first_positive_score1 = map_dbl(data, get_field2, "is_first_positive", "score_1"),
           first_positive_score2 = map_dbl(data, get_field2, "is_first_positive", "score_2"))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(approach1(), approach2())
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>  approach1() 19.849982 24.047509 26.470304 25.001731 26.896622 95.951980   100
#>  approach2()  2.159769  2.587905  2.783555  2.648321  2.740863  7.620581   100
```

Comment: thank you! I should’ve said in my post but there are multiple different logical columns (e.g. last_positive, first_negative_after_positive, etc) so the split / recombine approach works well but means a lot of code to do it. That’s definitely Plan B if I can’t find another way.

Comment: got it. I edited the post to show that simplifying your `guess_field` function yields a 10x improvement (on this small dataset).

Comment: thanks - gave a good increase in speed but still took >20 mins. Lots of columns being extracted is the issue I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a magic sauce. My bet is you would get at least a 100x improvement by moving to the alternative strategy. Otherwise, I don't think there's a way to improve your `map`+`get_field` approach. After all, there are only about 3 operations in there. There just isn't much room to improve.